# retrieving text in selenium using xpath?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, selenium

Hi i have this HTML code:

```
<tr class="odd events" style="">
<tr>
  <a title="Expand to see Actions" class="toggleEvent" name="actions_for_host_1" href="#"></a>
  <td id="7" colspan="6">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Low Alarm at 2010/06/25 07:09 ( <span title="2010/06/25 14:09 (UTC)" class="time_helper">Pacific</span> )</li>
      </ul>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How can I retrieve the `<li>` value using xpath and selenium ruby, so I get back `"Low Alarm at 2010/06/25 07:09 Pacific"`?

I don't know what the time and date will be but I know the `<li>` tag will always start with `Low Alarm`

thanks

sorry i couldn't phrase the question better.

Comment: Can you present the html structure before the li? i.e. the parents of li element you're interested in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `getText` command to retrieve the text using a suitable locator. There are a few possible locators that you could use, some suggestions are listed below:

XPath:

- locate the li based on the child span with the class time_helper

  ```
  //li[span[@class='time_helper']]
  ```
- locate the li based on the text starting with 'Low Alarm'

  ```
  //li[starts-with(text(), 'Low Alarm')]
  ```
- locate the li based on the text containing 'Low Alarm'

  ```
  //li[contains(text(), 'Low Alarm')]
  ```

CSS:

- locate the li based on the text starting with 'Low Alarm'

  ```
  css=li:contains(^Low Alarm)
  ```
- locate the li based on the text containing 'Low Alarm'

  ```
  css=li:contains(Low Alarm)
  ```

Comment: the trick here is the getText method. http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getText(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're specifically trying to use an xpath locator for this?
A CSS locator may do the job just as well, e.g.

```
css=li:contains('Low Alarm')
```